# Haskell - Does "IO ( )" means we give up the control of our program?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

We know that within a Haskell program, almost every piece of computation will return something, and such return values can be captured by another computation to apply more transformations on it. So if we "flatten" a normal Haskell program, it should be:

```
-- pure `a`: comes from Hask; not from file, network or any 
-- other side-effected devices

a → a' → a'' → a''' → .... → a_fin
```

Of course, this pure value might be "contexted". But we can still trace the path of alternating:

```
a → m a → m a' → a'' → n a''' → ... → z a_fin
```

For me, this shows that we can control our program to avoid side-effects and other 'surprises', which may be caused by missing of type system or our self.  But when the `IO ()` appears, there seems a missing:

```
--!! What happened between the IO () and the next computation ?

a → m a → m a' → IO () >> b → b' → m b'
```

The `IO ()` seems passing/receiving nothing, but it MUST read/write something at least. Especially if we consider the "receiver" process:

```
Sender::   a → m a → m a' → IO () >> b → b' → m b' ... → m b_fin
Receiver:: IO a' → IO a'' → IO a''' → ... → IO a_fin
```

In the sender, we can't see what happened on `a` after the `IO ()` . But if we consider both two processes , the missing part is back ! So we can say we missed or not missed the information, according to your point of view. Is this a information leak, and we just give up the control of our program, when we put the `IO ()` in the program ?

Thanks !

PS. Oh,and I also found that the Receiver, can only start computation with a "contexted" value, not a pure value, it's another question occurs in my mind...

Comment: "but it MUST read/write something at least" <- Not really, it could be just `return ()`.

Comment: Yes, but I can't find any "useful" ( for human ) program only does that.

Comment: Sometimes programmers check for errors even in situations where errors are impossible.  If a programmer writes `if x then print "Error occurred" else return ()` and `x` is always `False`, that code is equivalent to `return ()`.  It is still useful for humans because it protects against future programming errors that make `x` `True`.

Comment: Sometimes computations won't retern even in pure code, for example `a = a`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your comments it looks like that you think that because `IO ()`-typed computation does not return something useful the type system cannot guarantee that your program is correct.

First, the type system *does not* guarantee correctness of your program except in simple cases. In complex programs it is entirely possible to make logical mistake and your program will compile but return wrong results. It is programmer's duty to avoid logical errors, and type system is only one (powerful one indeed) tool.

Second point follows from the first. `IO` is a plain monad; it is the same type (from the point of view of type system, of course) as any other. AFAIK it does not receive some special treatment from the type system. The value of type `IO ()` does mean 'an impure computation which, when executed, may affect outside world in some way and which does not yield anything meaningful' and nothing more. Consider value of type `State Int ()`: it means 'a stateful computation which, when executed, may do something with current state of type `Int` and which does not yield anything useful'. You see, both of these values have some kind of side effect and both of them has the same meaning related to computation *result*. They are equivalent in this way from the view of type system. But the second one is perfectly *pure* computation. You easily can turn it to some meaningful value (in this case, `Int`) using `execState` or `runState`.

Comment: Thank you let me realize that the type system isn't a panacea for the correction of programs.But the `State Int ()`, just like you said, will be observable after you run it ( get the final state value ). We can observe that result value is correct or not in our program. On the contrary, while we execute an `IO ()`, it's "output" is totally invisible. We don't even know if our `putStrLn` will output the string, or launch a nuclear missle.

Comment: But as I described, if you consider both the Receiver and the Sender process, the `IO ()` will become a portal, wrap a value form this process to another, and then we can trace it's flow. Is it possible to make a wrapper, which receive all `IO ()` and capture it's "output", no matter what it is ( bytestream, character string, etc.) ? If so, we can use a `Wrapper (IO ()) out` or something like that to see what it did, and no need to jump to another process ( but I think the type maybe a big problem ).

Comment: I don't think it is possible to create such wrapper in plain Haskell, at least not in a way you have described. While `IO` monad does not receive special treatment from type system, it is still being handled very specially by Haskell runtime, and without hacking the runtime you cannot do so. You can do something less general by wrapping `IO` monad into some monad transformers stack and provide functions working in this stack which will track your actions, but I don't think you can do more than this.

Comment: Also, it seems you are distinguishing `IO ()` from something like `IO Int`. Regarding to your question this is not correct too, because `IO Int` is not required to have as its result in global sense only one integral value. It still can perfrom side effects. `()` type contains one value `()`, and `Int` contains a range of integers from -2^31 to 2^31-1, so what? `()` is still a value. `Prelude` could safely contain `putStrLn :: String -> IO Int`, being declared like `putStrLn s = putStrLn' s >> return 0`, where `putStrLn'` is current version of `putStrLn`, and you wouldn't even know that.

Comment: Yes, I admit that I got a little confused. Besides that, I will consider more about the "effects/output" of any `IO a`, and how to program correctly with them.

Answer (score 3):

No.  You're thinking that each action in the chain can only see the result of its immediate predecessor; but in reality, each action has access, if it wants, to the result of **any** previous action.  Just to use a toy example:

```
return 5 >>= (\x -> putStrLn "mwahaha!" >>= (\_ -> putStrLn "x is " ++ show x >>= (\_ -> return ())))
```

Note the scope of the variable `x`—it extends to the end of the whole expression.  (The parentheses are optional there, but I put them in to make the scope obvious.)

Consider again the type of `>>=`:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

This can be paraphrases "use the result of an action of type `m a` and a function of type `a -> m b` to construct **the rest of the program**" (not just the next action).

Actions also have context to mutable memory and any I/O device available to the program, so that's also another mechanism by which an action can communicate with another.  Two actions of type `IO ()`, for all you know, can communicate through shared memory or by sharing a file.

Comment: Thank you, I missed the scope problem. But just like your example shows, the type system can't ensure that the `ptrStrLn` works fine. If the `ptrStrLn` did something wrong, says that it did not put the string out, or even worse, it instead put a wrong string out, the programmer and compiler both can't found that error until runtime. On the other hand, if a `getLine::IO String` got wrong, we can know that because it had a return value, which can be checked by type system or the "next" action ( still cause error when running, but can be founded in the program, not outside )

Comment: Take the function `(+) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer`, which is meant to add two `Integer`s.  The type system can't ensure that this function works correctly; `1 + 1 :: Integer` will typecheck, but it's still possible that it might evaluate to `3`.  The programmer won't be able to discover that error until the program runs.  So in general, this is not a problem that's specific to `IO`, it's simply the fact that all that Haskell's type system can do is detect some class of type errors, not prove the correctness of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from a certain point of view values of type `IO a` pull information out of thin air; information that doesn't originate in the inputs to the function that produced them. That's inevitable, as the entire *point* of `IO` is to write computations whose results depend on (and can effect) the world outside the program. The information that results from a call to `readFile` resides in a file on disk, not in your program. So yes, you're "giving up control" in the sense that the results of any program using any `IO` action depend on thing that are not under the control of the program you're writing. But *every* program is like this; the only way to avoid it is to not use `IO` (or any mechanism of communicating with the outside world) at all, and then your program is just an extraordinarily complicated way of writing down whatever the final result is.

But the type system never cares about the actual intput/output **values**, and it doesn't prove that they are correct, even when `IO` is not involved. In type checking a function of type `Integer -> String` all it does is verify that it is implemented with operations that will indeed accept an `Integer` and return a `String`. It has *no conception* of whether the **correct** string is produced.

You can even "lie" to the type system; `undefined` is a valid definition for *any* function, which then gives you a function that e.g. takes an Integer and returns a String as far as the type system is concerned. But that doesn't mean it's a correct implementation of that function; and any other function defined in terms of this one will be incorrect too, and the type checker doesn't care at all.

Likewise, a function of type `Integer -> IO ()` checks that the function uses operations that accept an `Integer` and produce an `IO ()`. That's **all** that type checking proves, and this is no different for `IO ()` than for `IO Integer` or for `Integer`, or *any* other type.

Comment: Thanks. It's my fault to be too obsessing about the type system, and you pointed out the problem about information "vaporizing" with `IO a`. That's why I try to propose making a `Wrapper (IO a) out`, which can capture all things output from the IO ( they're not really vaporized, but will pass to something outside the program ). Of course, as @VladimirMatveev mentioned, it may be a impossible thing.

Answer (score 0):

This chain consists of “states” of your program (well, sort of). Let’s consider a simple program:

```
main = do
  let a = 4  -- 1
  print a    -- 2
  print a    -- 3
```

Here, after step 1 your state is `4`. But after step 2 this `4` doesn’t disappear — your state now is (4, ()). After step 3 it is (4, (), ()) and so on.

---

To make long story short, information which will be used later remains in the chain. It doesn’t disappear after `IO ()`.

Comment: What I concern is: even though we care about pure and impure very much, and the Haskell's type system help either program or programmer a lot, we still will feel helpless when the program had some or many IO (). In this situation, you can't rely on the type system to guaranty your program is correct, because the type can't represent what does the action will do -- unless you also check all the process "receive" the action, like the Sender in my question. This worries me because I suddenly found my faith about the type system got shaken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the question is, but I'll throw in an answer in the case my intuition is correct, anyhow.

The fact of the matter is that, if you were to solely look at the type of the program's constituent functions, you can come to one of two conclusions:

1. Your program does not use IO, and the computations are therefore guaranteed to be pure, and thus produce no side-effects(Within certain limits, of course.)

or

1. Your program does use IO, and is therefore not pure, and it cannot be guaranteed that it does not produce side-effects.

Of course, there are computations within the spectrum of all possible IO computations that produce no side-effects, just as there are computations whose types indicate purity, but use unsafe functions such as `unsafePerformIO`. But in general, you can look at the type of a pure function and say: This function will not fail on disk IO, network IO or anything of the sorts. That same guarantee does not hold for IO computations.

Comment: Yes, I know these difference between pure and impure functions. But I still feel something wrong about `IO ()` : it means "the type system  in this process doesn't care about the computation's input/output anymore". So we can't check whether the input/output of the action is correct, and thus we can't ensure our entire program ( which used the action ) is correct, unless we or the type system do check the Receiver process, too.

Answer (score 0):

`IO ()` means that the computation may be influenced both by past `IO` actions, and that it may influence future `IO` actions in your "computation chain". However, non-IO values (anything that, if it has a monad stack, does not have IO anywhere in the stack) that follow *cannot* be directly affected, since `()` is the trivial value, and that is all they are allowed to depend on. They can be indirectly affected if they depend on some `IO a` that is affected. This is ignoring `unsafePerformIO`, which should only be used in such a way that the above explanation still essentially holds true.